# I can't import some libraries, including Pil, why is that?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I use PyCharm, it appears an error and a message that PIL doesn't exist. But, if I use Sublime Text, the program runs correctly. Also in PyhCharm the `site-packages` folder, it's coloured orange and it seems to be disabled, see image bellow:

[[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the following method,

1. Go to the settings (`Ctrl+Alt+S`) and select the next options
2. Select the folder which wants to convert into python sources in my case "./src" and tap in Source tag (Mark as..) then it added on the left panel also tap Apply or Ok.

I hope it will work!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've already solved the problem. The thing was that I had something wrong  with my interpreter, but thank you very much!